# save existing chart to Configuration

Tags: java, charts, phantomjs, vaadin

I am trying to save the charts as SVG( in vaadin) using phantomjs. I found one example from https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-charts-export-from-browser-to-svg-and-pdf and it works for me. 
Though, I am making couples of different charts and want them to be downloadable. I see

```
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.getChart().setType(ChartType.PIE);
```

But I already have charts. I was wondering how can I include the existing chart into configuration instead of creating new again like above.